# inconsistent parenthesis displayed in JavaFX for localized right-to-left language strings

Tags: java, javafx, localization, javafx-8, right-to-left

For right-to-left languages, what controls how JavaFX 8 displays parenthesis? For Example:

```
my_en.properties: TEST=Three (equals) five.
my_ar.properties: TEST=\u062B\u0644\u0627\u062B\u0629 (\u064A\u0633\u0627\u0648\u064A) \u062E\u0645\u0633\u0629.
```

Setting nodeOrientation in JavaFX scenes displays the Arabic correctly:
[image]

But then other times, the parenthesis are not as expected:

```
my_en.properties: TEST=Three (4) five.
my_ar.properties: TEST=\u062B\u0644\u0627\u062B\u0629 (4) \u062E\u0645\u0633\u0629.
```

Results in:
 [image]

This happens for various phrases inside the parenthesis, but not consistently for all OS (Windows 32/64, OSX especially).

How to we make this work "correctly" for R2L languages?

Answer (score 1):

Adding the right-to-left-mark character before each parenthesis works around the problem:

```
my_ar.properties: TEST=\u062B\u0644\u0627\u062B\u0629 \u200F(4)\u200F \u062E\u0645\u0633\u0629.
```